# Transformating from cartesian to spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, line-integrals

I am doing a simple line integral, but I am getting an inconsistency. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

$$ \int_{C} \vec{F}(\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}).d\vec{l} = \int(\hat{z}).(dx\hat{x}+dy\hat{y}+dz\hat{z}) = z $$

When I try to do the same integral in spherical coordinates I get:

$$ \int_{C} \vec{F}(\vec{r},\vec{\theta},\vec{\phi}).d\vec{l} = \int[cos(\theta)\hat{r}-sin(\theta)\hat{\theta}].(dr\hat{r}+rd\hat{\theta}+rsin(\theta)d\phi\hat{\phi}) = rcos(\theta)+rcos(\theta)=2z \ne z $$

Comment: How did you derive $(dr\hat{r}+rd\hat{\theta}+rsin(\theta)d\phi\hat{\phi}) $?

Comment: It is an infinitesimal displacement in each coordinate of the spherical system. I thought this was the right one to use because I (could) have a displacement in each of the 3 versors $(\hat{r},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi})$.